# Flask-Admin can_create = True only for a given user

Tags: flask, flask-login, flask-admin

I am using Flask-Admin in conjunction with Flask-Login and mongoengine.

I wish to customize views depending on users. Hereafter, an example with `can_create`, that allows model creation.

---

```
class MyModelView(ModelView):
    column_exclude_list = ['password']
    def is_accessible(self):
        if (login.current_user.login != 'admin'):
            can_create=False
        return login.current_user.is_authenticated()
```

---

Such a piece of code has no effect: all users can still create, no difference between admin and non-admin users.

Thanks a lot for any hint on how it's possible to allow model creation only to a given user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look like that you just created local variable `can_create`, so you can try `self.can_create = False`. But `flask-admin` create one instance of `View` and this can be problems with concurrency. However better separate logic for checking accessibility and changing view state. So probably better use next code:

```
class MyModelView(ModelView):
    column_exclude_list = ['password']

    def is_accessible(self):
        return login.current_user.is_authenticated()

    @property
    def can_create(self):
        return login.current_user.login == 'admin'
```

Comment: It's surprising how often i forget that making something a property getter can solve my problems!