# How to separate access Flask-Admin on can_create?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I want to making a condional on Flask-Admin methods feature.

But confusing about how to give a conditional between users roles, let says in the **can_create** feature.

Here is the snippet of my modelview:

```
class UserModelView(sqla.ModelView):

    if current_user.has_role == 'superuser':
        can_create = True
    elif current_user.has_role == 'client':
        can_create = False
```

But I'm getting few errors, and I have also tried the different ways, like this:

```
class UserModelView(sqla.ModelView):
    def is_visible(self):
        if current_user.has_role == 'superuser':
            can_create = True
        elif current_user.has_role == 'client':
            can_create = False
```

and I have also tried it with other methods on `BaseModelView` class, but still don't work like I want.

So.. is it possible to give conditional in that feature..?

Comment: have you tried this solution already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137601/flask-admin-can-create-true-only-for-a-given-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17145104/8070090) base on @gitter advice, and it works in **can_create** feature, thanks @gitter.

But unfortunately it won't work in another conditional like **form_excluded_columns**

.

**EDIT**:
For methods *(ie: **can_create**)* from **BaseModelView** Class I following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17145104/8070090)

But for another methods like **form_excluded_columns**, I'm using [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47469875/8070090) , and [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42528619/8070090) can also work.

Comment: If you are looking for different admin views per role, a solution could be to add multiple flask-admin instances like this https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues/55

Comment: That's not seems I can use `sqla.ModelView` there, what I want is to manage two models in different `ModelView` base on user roles.

Comment: Add the view twice (use different names to avoid blueprint collisions). Set up each one for a different role access and setup each view with the necessary settings. That should do the trick.